# Merchant's name on the payment sheet is missing

Tags: ios, payment, applepay, merchant-account

I had **submitted** my SwiftUI application but it got **rejected** because there is no merchant name in the **Apple pay** sheet.

I am using Apple pay in my app. Recently, when I uploaded my app to the apple developer account for review, it got rejected with the following reason:

Your app uses Apple Pay as a purchasing mechanism but does not provide the necessary material purchase information to the user prior to the sale of goods and services.

Specifically, your app does not include the following:

- Merchant's name on the payment sheet

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to provide all of the necessary material purchase information to users upfront.

Resources

For more information on Apple Pay, please review the Apple Pay documentation.

[image: apple pay]

How can I **solve** this as there is no option to add a merchant name in **PKPaymentRequest**?

Comment: I am showing the total amount as:
`let total = PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Total", amount: NSDecimalNumber(string: "\(total)"), type: .final)
        paymentSummaryItems.append(total)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the screen shot that Apple have sent you, the word "Total" should be the name of your merchant.  It should say something like "Pay Acme Ltd"

The last item in the `PKPaymentRequest`'s `paymentSummaryItems` array is used for the grand total amount.

Refer to the [documentation for this property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpaymentrequest/1619231-paymentsummaryitems)

> Apple Pay uses the last item in the paymentSummaryItems array as the grand total for the purchase.
>
> The PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController class displays this item differently than the rest of the summary items. As a result, there are additional requirements placed on both its amount and its label.
>
> - Set the grand total amount to the sum of all the other items in the array. This amount must be greater than or equal to zero.
> - Set the **grand total label to the name of your company**. This label represents the person or company receiving payment.